# Can Windows 10 and Ubuntu bootloaders reside on one partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I was having Windows 10 on my system and I installed Ubuntu 15.04 specifying boot partition same as where Windows 10 bootloader was residing.

Now in the grub it is showing both Windows 10 and Ubuntu but it is able to boot only from Ubuntu. In Ubuntu it is showing all my Windows 10 files intact as well as files in boot volume.

When I repaired my windows Windows 10 bootloader using bootrec then system neither boot from Ubuntu nor from windows 10.

I again reinstalled Ubuntu and it is now booting from Ubuntu but not from Windows 10.

Comment: In ubuntu update your grub 'sudo update-grub' install updates sudo apt-get update' reboot; go into bios and check safe and fast boot is disabled save changes and try to boot into Windows

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is booting in EFI mode, then both the Ubuntu boot loader (GRUB 2, by default) and the Windows boot loader can reside on the same [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) The ESP is a FAT partition that's intended for this purpose -- to hold boot loaders. Microsoft requires that manufacturers use EFI mode for pre-installed Windows 8 and later computers, so if the computer came with Windows 10, chances are it uses EFI mode and what you describe *should* work. The most likely explanation of the symptoms you're describing is a defective firmware, perhaps in conjunction with some misapplied fixes intended to overcome such defects.

OTOH, in BIOS mode, boot loader code goes in the Master Boot Record (MBR; aka the first sector of the hard disk) and in various follow-on locations. Typically, Windows boots from the MBR to the Partition Boot Record (PBR; aka the first sector of the partition) to files in the NTFS volume, whereas GRUB boots from the MBR to some post-MBR code to files in the Linux directory tree. If you install GRUB to a partition rather than to an MBR, though, it will take over the PBR. If you install GRUB to the PBR of a Windows partition, then that partition will no longer boot Windows. The symptoms are consistent with what you've reported, at least as far as I understand them. You're most likely to encounter a BIOS-booting Windows 10 on a system you've upgraded from Windows 7 or earlier, installed yourself from scratch, or re-installed yourself over an earlier installation. The solution to your problem in this case is likely to involve using Windows tools to restore the PBR (and probably the MBR), then re-installing GRUB to either the MBR or the PBR *of an Ubuntu filesystem partition*.

Because EFI-mode and BIOS-mode booting are so different, fixing your problem requires that you know which boot mode you're using. In Windows, boot mode is tied pretty tightly to partition table type, which you can determine in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo parted -l | grep Table
```

The output should specify your disk's partition table type, as in:

```
Partition Table: gpt
```

This indicates GPT, and therefore an EFI-mode boot of Windows. If it reads `msdos` rather than `gpt`, then that indicates MBR, and therefore a BIOS-mode boot of Windows.

If you can't get it fixed once you know the boot mode, please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) on your system. This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us additional diagnostic information. Also, please specify the make and model of your computer.